# Self adjoint inverse

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, functional-calculus

I'm reading some functional analysis and it's after lunch so I can't think. Can someone please help with this quick question. I have the following:

Let $T\in B(H)$ be a self adjoint operator and $\varepsilon>0$. Let $p$ be the spectral projection of $T$ corresponding to the Borel subset $[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$ (that is, the indicator function of $[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$ applied to $T$ by Borel functional calculus). Then the following operator $$S = (1-p)T+\varepsilon p$$ has a self adjoint bounded inverse.

Why? Is there an obvious inverse I am missing, or is this some bounded inverse theorem (or one of the other functional analysis theorems) business.

Comment: $S$ corresponds to the function equal $1$ on the interval $x\in [-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$ and $x$ for |x|>\varepsilon. Such function has a bounded inverse. The inverse operator is equal {1\over \varepsilon}P$ on the range of $P.$ But on the range of $I-P$, i.e. on $\ker P$ according to me there is no explicit formula, which does not make use of the  spectral integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was about to post an answer, when I saw that what I had to say had been said in a comment. Some readers may wonder what it means for an operator to "correspond to" a function. That's a medium-long story - my favorite version is not the most popular one, decided to mark this community-wiki and post a complete answer for readers who don't know that stuff.
Note again that the proof is contained in a comment above, of which this is just an exegesis.

A suitable version of the Spectral Theorem says that wlog $H=L^2(\mu)$ and $T$ is given by pointwise multiplication by $m\in L^\infty(\mu)$: $$(Tf)(x)=m(x)f(x).$$In this context $p$ is given by multiplcation by $$k_\epsilon=\chi_{[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}\circ m,$$and $S$ is multiplication by $$M=(1-k_\epsilon)m+\epsilon k_\epsilon.$$Considering a total of two cases shows that $1/M$ is bounded. (Also $1/M$ is real-valued since $m$ is; that's the "self-adjoint" part.)

Comment: Good that you have posted the answer, as my comment is edited poorly (typed on my mobile phone). Besides on function space the explanation is clearer.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help